# I'm not able to get my stack to work

Tags: java

I am reading in from a file numbers spaced out by _ (1-9) and then with each number you do something to a stack. I'm just trying to get my case to read each item in the array and do something for each number but i can't seem to get it to work.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    FileReader file = new FileReader("textfile.txt");
    int[] integers;
    integers = new int[100];
    int i = 0;
    try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file)) {
        while (input.hasNext()) {
            integers[i] = input.nextInt();
            i++;
        }

        Stack<Integer> nums = new Stack<>();
        int number = integers[i];
        switch (number) {
            case '1':
                nums.push(5);
                System.out.println(nums.peek());
                break;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your specific issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your switch statement, take the single quotes out from the number 1.

`'1'` is of type `char`

`1` is of type `int`

Also, when you try to get a number here:

```
int number = integers[i];
```

It's always going to be `0` because `i` is now an index greater than what you've actually populated in your array.

Comment: so take that out and make it switch(integers[i]);   ?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you're just trying to learn a bit about `Stack` and switch statements, try `switch(1)`. Add more `case` statements and see what happens.

Comment: take the numbers from the file read in and then perform a certain task with them and put what it equals onto the stack.

Comment: What's the "certain task"? That's the meat of this. Doesn't sound like you would need a switch statement at all. Just do your number crunching task, then `nums.push(yourResult);`

Comment: for each number read in from the file there is a task  #0-pop 2 numbers off the stack add them and put the answer back on the stack #1-same but subtract first from second #2- same but multiply #3- same but divide first by the second #4- same but divide the first by second and put remainder on the stack #5-place the next number read in on the stack(must be range 1-9) #6-same but perform an arithmetic AND on the two numbers #7-Same but perform an arithmetic OR on them #8-pop 1 number off the stack, square it, put answer back #9-Remove 1 number from the stack and throw it away